# SSD not detected by BIOS but visible in gparted and windows disk management

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd

I have an HDD and an SSD(newly installed) on my Lenovo laptop.

- **HDD** - Windows 10 + Ubuntu 18
- **SSD** - Ubuntu 20 (freshly installed)

However, I am unable to boot into the SSD ubuntu since it neither shows up in GRUB menu on HDD nor is the SSD visible in BIOS menu/boot menu. However, the SSD is visible in gparted as well as disc management in Windows with the appropriate partitions.

I can boot into both the OS on my HDD in Legacy mode but BIOS can't find any bootable device in the UEFI mode. None of the existing questions resemble my case and hence had to post this question. How can I fix this (I don't mind reinstalling the SSD)? Will add any more details asked.

Comment: It looks like Ubuntu is installed in legacy mode.

Comment: @Pilot6 but is that a/the problem ?

Comment: If it bothers you, then it is a problem. You can reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode or chnange it from legacy to UEFI, but it's a bit tricky.

Comment: @Pilot6 Just to be clear, I am unable to boot into the SSD ubuntu 20 in all modes.

Comment: Did you install SSD into DVD caddy space? While DVDs are bootable, many systems will not boot a drive in that space.

Comment: Yes I did install in the dvd caddy space. I'm still booting into the grub on hdd but if I try to boot the SSD ubuntu from there on, it throws the error - can't find chs values. Load kernel first